# how to retrieve value in text box and display

Tags: php, forms, post, text

i have a text box. how to take the value that user enter in text box and display in the same page and the same form. my code is not working.

**My code**

```
<input name="bulan" type="text" id="bulan" value="00" size="2" maxlength="2" />
      Bulan</td>
<? $bulan = $_POST['bulan'];
      echo $bulan;?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do that when the form is submitted or when the field is filled?

Comment: when the field is filled..is that possible?

Comment: Yes, using javascript, not using php.

Comment: how?guide me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jQuery for this
for example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#bulan").keyup(function() {
                    var bulan = $("#bulan").val()
                    $(".bulan").text(bulan);
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input name="bulan" type="text" id="bulan" value="00" size="2" maxlength="2" />
        <div class="bulan"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to display it? i tried to run but it only have a text box for input and no display after it.

Comment: have you embed jquery to your HTML <head> ?

Comment: I just created a HTML file using this codes, and it works. the div content changed according to the input text value as you type on keyboard. Is this what you need?

Comment: @Bryant..thanks for helping me. it is working. i'm sorry about my mistake.. :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="bulan" **disabled="disabled"** type="text" id="bulan" value="00" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?=$_POST['bulan']?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then i would do like this. .

```
<form action=<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="POST" >
    <b>Bulan : </b><input name="bulan" type="text" id="bulan" value="00" size="2" maxlength="2" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$bulan = $_POST['bulan'];
echo $bulan;
?>
```

and always use `<?php` this tag for opening php. Not the short one `<?`.

Comment: its because the value of $_post['bulan'] will not be set initially. so in the place of $bulan = $_POST['bulan'] you must check it with if, if(isset($_POST['bulan']) { . . .. . . ...echo '';